# Marks misaligned in Altair Gantt chart when axis labels are wrapped

Tags: python, altair, gantt-chart

I'm generating a Gantt chart using Altair v5.1.1 and I find that, when I try to implement multi-line axis labels, some marks are misaligned.

The data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'Dataset': 'A - Lorem ipsum dolor',
                    'Start': '2016-01-01',
                    'End': '2016-12-31',
                    'Version': 'X'},
                   {'Dataset': 'A - Lorem ipsum dolor',
                    'Start': '2017-01-01',
                    'End': '2021-12-31',
                    'Version': 'Y'},
                   {'Dataset': 'A - Lorem ipsum dolor',
                    'Start': '2022-01-01',
                    'End': '2022-12-31',
                    'Version': 'Z'},
                   {'Dataset': 'B - Sit amet consectetur',
                    'Start': '2016-01-01',
                    'End': '2018-12-31',
                    'Version': 'X'},
                   {'Dataset': 'B - Sit amet consectetur',
                    'Start': '2019-01-01',
                    'End': '2022-12-31',
                    'Version': 'Y'}])
```

The code underlying the chart, simplified to configure only what's necessary for the example:

```
bars = (
    alt.Chart(df)
    .mark_bar(opacity=0.7)
    .encode(
        x=alt.X('Start:T'),
        x2=alt.X2('End:T'),
        y=alt.Y('Dataset:N'),
        color=alt.Color('Version:N'),
    )
    .properties(height=120)
)
```

If I don't wrap the y-axis labels, the chart looks as expected:

[image]

However, if I change the y-axis labels [to lists](https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/2376#issuecomment-1023351012) for multi-line axis labels, I find that the marks for Dataset B where Version != X are misaligned on the Y axis, not only such that they appear to correspond to Dataset A, but are also offset by -3 pixels.

[image]

Here's a screenshot of the dataframe, in case you don't want to run the code:

[image]